# Do I have to get rid of my mods to play multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have some mods downloaded for a single player world I play on and I was wondering, if I want to play in multiplayer, will I need to get rid of these mods? Similarly, if I have multiple single player worlds with different mods in both, should I have only the mods needed for the world in question in my mods folder? For instance, in one world if had the more enchantments mod and in the other orespawn, would I have to take out the enchantments.jar when I play the orespawn world?

Comment: Normally no, it just won't work on that server. If you try to use it, it will either bug out, error code, or the server might kick you if it detects it.

Comment: @Ashwin A friend of mine visited a server with mods, and the mods just didn't work there.

Comment: @PanV first thing I wrote, "it just wont work on that server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No for multiplayer:** you don't have to take them out of the mod folders for servers. Just don't try to do something with the mod or else you'll be kicked by the server or you will crash your client.

**yes for singleplayer:** If you play singleplayer though you might want to switch the mods out for different worlds as mods will work on any world once they are installed and may have direct influence on world generation. If you then uninstall mods they may corrupt your world to the point you can't recover it or leave you with an unplayable world generation.

Example: uninstalling the better water mod (a mod that replaces all water in a world) on a world that had it installed, will delete all water blocks within any chunk that you have ever loaded.

Comment: That makes sense. When you say just switch the mods out for different worlds, you mean remove them from the mods folder I assume? As long as i'm not playing that world, removing those mods wouldn't corrupt anything would it?

Comment: @TheKalkara131 yeah you just have to take them out of the folder. You can just leave then into another folder on you desktop to swich from there easly

Answer (score 0):

No, You do not need to remove your Mods to play Multiplayer

- Use of Modded Items WILL Result in a Internal Server Error Kick.
- Mods on Multiplayer may cause un-needed lag to your client.

You can toggle Forge in the Profile to disable mods for a short time to reduce lag. Loading the Modded Worlds will result in Modded Items being wiped upon forced join.